# select rows from main table based on highest date in child table between a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry for the confusing title.

I've this table:

```
ApplicantID    Applicant Name
-------------------------------
1              Sandeep
2              Thomas
3              Philip
4              Jerin
```

ALong with this child table which is connected with the above table:

```
DetailsID      ApplicantID      CourseName        Dt
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1                  1             C1               10/5/2014
2                  1             C2               10/18/2014
3                  1             c3               7/3/2014
4                  2             C1               3/2/2014
5                  2             C2               10/18/2014
6                  2             c3               1/1/2014
7                  3             C1               1/5/2014
8                  3             C2               4/18/2014
9                  3             c3               2/23/2014
10                 4             C1               3/15/2014
11                 4             C2               2/20/2014
12                 4             C2               2/20/2014
```

I want to get  `applicantsID`, for example, when I specify a date range from
`4/20/2014` to `3/5/2014`  I should have:

```
ApplicantID    Applicant Name
-------------------------------
3              Philip
4              Jerin
```

That means the applicants from the main table that must be in the second table and also the highest date of the second table must fall in the specified date range. Hope the scenario is clear.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Can you show us what you have?

Comment: Looks pretty straight-forward, what have you tried so far?

Comment: what's the problem exactly? Did you try anything?

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: what is the format of the column `Dt` ?

Comment: Sorry I had no idea how to compare the highest dates in the group of each applicants in the child table with the date range since highest date is the important point. Not just any dates of that applicant to fall on the date range.. thats the thing made me confused

Comment: @Begueradj MM/dd/yyyy is the date format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pull the `MAX` per `ApplicantId` with a `GROUP BY` in a sub-query, then `JOIN` to that result.  This should work for you:

```
Select  A.ApplicantId, A.[Applicant Name]
From    ApplicantTableName  A
Join
(
    Select  D.ApplicantId, Max(D.Dt) DT
    From    DetailsTableName    D
    Group By D.ApplicantId
) B On A.ApplicantId = B.ApplicantId
Where   B.DT Between '03/05/2014' And '04/20/2014'
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use window analytic function `row_number` to get applicant with maximum date in the given time range.

```
select T1.[ApplicantID], [Applicant Name]
from Table1 T1
join ( select [ApplicantID], 
              ROW_NUMBER() over ( partition by [ApplicantID] order by Dt desc) as rn
       from Table2
       where Dt  BETWEEN '3/5/2014' AND '4/20/2014'
      ) T
on T1.[ApplicantID] = T.[ApplicantID]
and T.rn =1
```